# How to get markdown files hosted on github pages to show up on a react app?

Tags: html, reactjs, github

I want to show some markdown files that are currently hosted on GitHub pages on my own site. The markdowns are in a hierarchy. The final result to be similar to: https://npr.api-docs.io/2.0/welcome/overview with the list of files on the left like a menu and each menu item opens the corresponding page on my site instead of redirecting to GitHub pages

Would be nice to know if anybody has already tried this

Answer (score 0):

A service (with a free tier) proposing a similar result is [`gitbook.com`](https://www.gitbook.com/), described in [`GitbookIO/gitbook`](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook).

> GitBook is a command line tool (and Node.js library) for building beautiful books using GitHub/Git and Markdown (or AsciiDoc).
>   Here is an example: [Learn Javascript](https://gitbookio.gitbooks.io/javascript/content/).

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/c1b6c55fca8e171120ce1fd73afcee699cc2a98f/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f476974626f6f6b494f2f676974626f6f6b2f6d61737465722f707265766965772e706e67]

Another approach would be to use [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) to generate a static website with a [documentation-like theme](https://themes.gohugo.io/tags/documentation/)

[image: https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/df0259bd2eb377a611a985c7914d6d50beb319e1/8d195/hugo-theme-techdoc/screenshot-hugo-theme-techdoc_hubc933344915d7016fa8cfdaf4a8842d2_191807_1500x1000_fill_catmullrom_top_2.png]